# Laravel, autoload classes based on an input array of class names

Tags: laravel, autoload

I have various classes, e.g.

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Notifications;

class FirstNotification implements NotificationInterface {
    public function getMessage() {
        return 'first message';
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Notifications;

class SecondNotification implements NotificationInterface {
    public function getMessage() {
        return 'second message';
    }
}
```

I then have an array like: `['First','Second']`.

I'm using:

```
foreach (['First','Second'] as $class_prefix) {

    $class = "MyApp\Notifications\\{$class_prefix}Notification";
    $object = new $class();
    echo $object->getMessage();
}
```

but it feels a bit hacky - is there a better/more standard way to do this? The array is supplied elsewhere and will be different depending on the user - my aim is to be able to easily create classes that implement my interface and know this loop will be able to show their messages if they exist.

I ideally don't want to have to add a use statement for all the classes upfront, or pass them into a constructor, I just want magic to happen!

Comment: The code you supplied looks actually pretty fine to me. What's not working? (you might need to add a backslash in front of `MyApp` though)

Comment: I guess it just feels a bit hacky - I don't really like using variable variables, but maybe there is not a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't actually mean *autoload* but rather instantiate the class. Autoloading is the process of including all the files in your application so the contents (usually classes) can be used. If you are using Laravel 5 and you follow PSR-4 (namespace matches directory structure) you don't have to do anything to make those classes available.

The code you already have looks fine and probably works. However you could make use of Laravels [Service Container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container) to resolve the class. This has quite a few advantages, one being the availability of automatic dependency injection...

```
foreach (['First','Second'] as $class_prefix) {
    $object = app()->make("MyApp\Notifications\\{$class_prefix}Notification");
    echo $object->getMessage();
}
```

Or even this:

```
foreach (['First','Second'] as $class_prefix) {
    echo app()->callClass("MyApp\Notifications\\{$class_prefix}Notification@getMessage");
}
```

However, both will cause an exception if the class doesn't exist. You can check for that beforehand or just catch the exception:

```
foreach (['First','Second'] as $class_prefix) {
    try{
        $object = app()->make("MyApp\Notifications\\{$class_prefix}Notification");
        echo $object->getMessage();
    }
    catch(ReflectionException $e){
        // whooops
    }
}
```

Comment: OK awesome - that seems more normal - you are right as well, I didn't mean autoload, but auto instantiation when needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually - a quick question - I don't consider the lack of this class to be an Exception - so I'd rather not throw one, but do an if class_exists first - is there a method from app() that does that, or would I just use a normal `if (class_exists("MyApp\…")){}` statement?

Comment: No unfortunately the container doesn't have such a method. You have to use `class_exists` (not that it would be a problem or anything)